# DocuSign Composite Template, identifying documents sent with composite template

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts, docusign-sdk

I'm having trouble with uniquely identifying the documents I get back from a signed envelope that was created using composite templates with server templates.

I'm creating my envelope with one document per composite. The document is specified by a server template. This server template has tabs that will be filled in by an inline template.

My initial thought was to uniquely identify the documents I get back by the document name. However, I now have a case where the same envelope will have two copies of the same server template but with different values filled in for the tabs. These documents will have the same name when returned by the envelopes::listDocuments endpoint so this no longer works as a unique identifier. I looked into setting EnvelopeDocumentFields but can't figure out how to add those to a document when creating an envelope with the composite template model. How can I add a unique identifier to each document that's created from a server template? I'm using the docusign-esign node.js sdk

EDIT: I tried documentFields and wasn't able to get them to work by adding them to the document field of the inlineTemplate or the document field of the composite template. I was able to use customFields, building them document by document and assigning them a documentId that I give the same as the compositeTemplateId, assuming that the documentId assigned will be 1,2,3... I added them all to the inlineTemplate of the last compositeTemplate and then when I retrieve the envelope I get the custom fields and then kinda just rely on the fact that the documentId is set as 1,2,3... and that the custom field with that id will give me the document info I want. I don't really like this - it seems hacky.

Comment: You have two identical documents inside an envelope and the only difference are the fields (tabs) that are associated with these documents?

Comment: Yes. They are the same type of tab but filled in with different values (which I am filling in when sending the envelope)

Comment: Then the only way is to use the documentId, each document has a unique documentId which you can use to identify the document. You need to store it so you later know which document is which

Comment: Yes, I think **[documentFields](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/#schema__envelopedefinition_documents_documentfields)** is the way to go. Can you add them to the inlineTemplate? Update your question to show what you tried.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Edited the post to reflect what I have tried. Would definitely appreciate feedback on my approach

Answer (score 0):

The EnvelopeDocuments:list method returns the document Id and order number as per below, can you use that to identify the document?

```
{
  "availableDocumentTypes": [
    {
      "isDefault": "true",
      "type": "electronic"
    }
  ],
  "display": "inline",
  "documentId": "1",
  "includeInDownload": "true",
  "name": "NDA.pdf",
  "order": "1",
  "pages": "3",
  "signerMustAcknowledge": "no_interaction",
  "type": "content",
  "uri": "/envelopes/44efc9e6-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-801410d6922d/documents/1"
},
```

Comment: Yes but can I set these values to what I want when creating the envelope so that I know what I'm looking for when I pull them back in?

Comment: Yes, you can set the value you want.

Comment: How? I'm using a server template for the document so I'm having trouble setting any other document fields

Comment: In that case, DocIds are regenerated when the call comes through based on the order they're fed in. To solve this you could use document field to identify the document. This blog describes exactly what you need: https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/the-trenches-how-to-track-recipients-and-documents-when-ids-change